# Is this possible using Azure Tables?

Tags: c#, azure, group-by, azure-table-storage

I get a error message “the method ‘join’ is not supported” in the below linq query:

```
tableServiceContext = new CustomTableServiceContext(storageAccount.TableEndpoint.AbsoluteUri, storageAccount.Credentials);
tableServiceContext.RetryPolicy = RetryPolicies.Retry(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
var results = (from c in tableServiceContext.CreateQuery<ChannelEntry>("Channels").AsTableServiceQuery<ChannelEntry>()
    join v in tableServiceContext.CreateQuery<VideoEntry>("Videos").AsTableServiceQuery<VideoEntry>() on c.PartitionKey equals v.ChannelID
    join h in tableServiceContext.CreateQuery<HitEntry>("Hits").AsTableServiceQuery<HitEntry>() on v.PartitionKey equals h.VideoID
    where c.RowKey.Equals(UserID)
    group h by h.RowKey into g
    select new BiggestFan { UserID = g.Key, Hits = g.Count() }).AsTableServiceQuery().Execute().OrderByDescending(b => b.Hits).Take(1);
```

If “join” is not supported in this context then what would be the most efficient way to do my query ?

I have Channels which are made up of Videos which in turn have Hits.  I’m trying to find the biggest fan (highest hits) of the currently logged in user.

What would be the most efficient way of doing this type of this without using joins?  Would I have to grab all the Channels then Videos and then Hits as 3 separate calls to the Table Storage and then do the joins after that?

Comment: For future reference, here is a list of the supported/unsupported Linq statements against table storage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd135725.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can't join. You have a couple options here.

1) Multiple scans - slap a couple of .ToArray() statements before you joins so that its doing the join in memory in your app. This is not performant but table storage is pretty fast. Really comes down to how many rows this will result in.

2) Denormalise your tables so that you have references to all the keys you need in a single table. This will let you get your results in 1 query, but means all insert/update logic needs to be updated.

Comment: How would that look for option 2 you suggested denormalizing ...?

If Channels have Videos and Videos have Hits, then would I still have 3 respective tables but store all the VideoIDs into the Channels Table, and likewise store the HitIDs into the Videos table?

Comment: Yes exactly. Replicate those Ids so that you don't need to join across so many tables at once. I'm expecting that the Hits table is the one to update like this since you are querying based on Hits and the Hits table is the one that sounds like it would have thousands of entries. Also I'm guessing that your content for Hits is essentially 'Write once' - in other words, you don't update a Hit record in the table, which means denormalised data is easy to implement since you don't have to worry about keeping your IDs sync'ed in future updates.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense esp the part about write once.  Obviously the date and person who hit the video needs to be known and will never be updated after that.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 things in your query that are not supported by Azure Table Storage (AZT, my abbreviation, not generally used by others) querys.

1. Joins
2. Grouping
3. Aggregate functions

The short version is that if you want to run an efficient query in AZT then you need to run it against just one table and query against the partition key or partition key and row key.

This doesn't mean that your base data has to be stored in just this one table, you can keep the structure that you currently have, but you may need to build a table that is basically an index to allow you to get the info that you want.  It might have a structure similar to this:

```
PartitionKey = ChannelUserId.PadWithLeadingZeros() + "-" + (int.MaxValue - NumberOfHits).PadWithLeadingZeros();
RowKey = Fan User Id;
```

Your query would then look something like this:

```
tableServiceContext = new CustomTableServiceContext(storageAccount.TableEndpoint.AbsoluteUri, storageAccount.Credentials);
tableServiceContext.RetryPolicy = RetryPolicies.Retry(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
var results = (from i in tableServiceContext.CreateQuery<BiggestFansIndex>("BiggestFansIndex").AsTableServiceQuery<BiggestFansIndex>()
    where i.PartitionKey.CompareTo(UserId.PaddedWithLeadingZeros()) >= 0
        && i.PartitionKey.CompareTo((UserId + 1).PaddedWithLeadingZeros()) < 0
    select i}).Take(1).Execute();
```

Your biggest problem I suspect will be keeping this index table up to date as I'm sure hits will change with reasonable regularity.

Answer (score 1):

Azure table storage is not suitable for such aggregate queries. I would suggest you to look into some No-SQL document databases such as CouchDB, MongoDB and RavenDB. But if you still want to use it you would require to denormalize the data.

Answer (score 1):

What others have said about not being able to do JOINs in Azure Tables is correct.  You can move it to SQL Azure where JOINs work as you expect, but it's far more expensive and slower than Azure tables.  However, assuming you stick with Azure tables:

In looking at this specific query, you could set up the partition key for the Hits table to like this:

**Hits Table:**
PartitionKey = UserId (of the owner of the channel)
RowKey = Timestamp (or something else unique)
UserId (of the user that performed the hit)
ChannelID
VideoID
(and other fields you want on the Hits table)

As others have said, you can't do aggregation on Azure table storage queries, so you have to pull all the data back into local memory (by calling Execute), then you can do the aggregation in memory.  Here is how to pull data from Table storage (this query is run on the Azure Table Storage server):

```
var allHits = 
    (
      from h in tableServiceContext.CreateQuery("Hits")
        .AsTableServiceQuery()
        where h.PartitionKey == CurrentUserId  // The currently logged in user
    ).Execute();
```

And then here is how you could aggregate it (this query is run in local memory):

```
var result = 
    (
      from h in allHits
      group h by h.UserId into g  // The User that performed the Hit
      select new BiggestFan { UserID = g.Key, Hits = g.Count() }
    )
    .OrderByDescending(b => b.Hits).FirstOrDefault();
```

This will technically work, but it won't scale.  Once various users become popular, it will be impractical to pull down all of a user's hits into local memory to run this query.  Plus you'll probably end up having to do paging on the data once it becomes too large to pull down all at once.

You could go further in denormalizing the data and calculate and store various totals as you go, so that when you need to run this Biggest-Fan query, all you need to retrieve are various pre-calculated totals.

However, this is only one query.  When designing your Azure table structure, you need to consider all of the queries you might want to do against them, how often they will be run, and how much data they will be operating against.  Then you can figure out the best structure for your data in Azure Tables.  I would recommend against designing your Azure tables around a single query, as you will likely need more queries in the future.